# Can the meter bar be raised X pixels?

Tags: html, meter

I would like to raise the meter bar X pixels to be centered with the text height (on either side of the bar). I want only the meter bar to be raised, and the text to remain in position.

I've tried padding-bottom but it raises the whole line.

Many thanks,

```
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
height: 10px;
}

TEXT <meter value="0.5"></meter> TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go!

```css
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
height: 10px;
margin-top: 2px; /* (16px - 10px) / 2 */
}

#meter {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="meter">
TEXT <meter value="0.5"></meter> TEXT
</div>
```

If you wanted the font smaller, you would update it to something like this:

```css
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
height: 10px;
margin-top: 1px; /* (12px - 10px) / 2 */
}

#meter {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="meter">
TEXT <meter value="0.5"></meter> TEXT
</div>
```